# Cypress intercept not matching url

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am fetching data with a network call:

```
https://mydomain.xxx/third-party-service/pragma?perPage=15&page=1
Request Method: GET
```

Trying to intercept it with code:

```
// Overriden not to clear localStorage authentication tokens
const clear = Cypress.LocalStorage.clear;
Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function(keys) {
  if (keys) {
    return;
  }
};

context('Navigation', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.login();
    cy.visit('/');
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.get('[data-test=test-burger]').click();
  });

  it('Tests table', () => {
    cy.get('[data-test=invoices]').click();
    cy.intercept('**/pragma**').as('getPragmaDocuments');
    cy.wait('@getPragmaDocuments');
    //....assertions here after API call is waited
  });
});
```

However, it does not intercept the network request.

Error I get:

*Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: getPragmaDocuments. No request ever occurred.Learn more*

Comment: Testing with `Cypress.minimatch` as [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Matching-URL) suggest show that URL is matched, can you give a [mre]?

Comment: I tried testing with `Cypress.minimatch`. It returns `true`. Edited my question including all code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see your problem, and I'm not sure why your "fix" worked, haha.

You need to start the `cy.intercept()` *before* the click, like this:

```
cy.intercept('**/pragma**').as('getPragmaDocuments');
cy.get('[data-test=invoices]').click();
cy.wait('@getPragmaDocuments');
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, I am not sure why my answer seemed to "fix" my problem. As it is sometimes working and sometimes not. My bad, thanks.

Comment: Maybe a race condition? The click action begins, but the intercept action initialized faster.